# Sharepoint 2010 - list item permission according to value in column

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a sharepoint list "**Notes**" with columns [Title] and [Department].

I fetch values for column [Department] from another list called "**Departments**" (columns [Id] and [Name].

**I want this**:

Everytime I add new record in "Notes", I want to set permission for this record according to permission set on the value in column Department.

So, basicaly, I SOMEHOW need to first set permissions, which users or groups has rigths for each department in list "Departments". After that, I need to inherit this permission in "Notes" list from the value of [Department].

**For example**:

Departments list would look like this

Billing (some permission for users or groups)

Operations (some permission for users or groups)

Sales (some permission for users or groups)

I want to add new record in "Notes" like "Hello, new item" and I chose department "Billing".

Now, I want that only users/groups which has rigths to see Billing records can see this record. No one else.

And so on... as soon as I add new record with [Department] Operations, I want only users/groups which have rigths to see Operations record to see only these records.

Is there any solution for me? I think it should has something to do with sharepoint designer workflow "Replace permission" but I never figured it out how to set as described above.

Thanks,

Jan

Comment: It is welcome to have a read at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It is possible to overwrite permissions in workflow using an Impersonation Step - I believe this will only work in SP 2010 workflows. However, I am not sure if it is possible to read the permission values of another list to pull that user information into a workflow. Are these Departments not set up as permission groups or in your AD?

Comment: well, that was my point - if it is possible to read permission data of item in another list, ... data in Notes list in column Deartment are are just records in Department list and each of the record in Department list has got its own permission set up.

Comment: Personally i would use a farm solution and event receivers to tackle your question

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the "Replace List Item Permissions" Action is the only way to achieve this without creating a custom event receiver. Here is a blog post about it: http://spcycle.blogspot.com.tr/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html.

Having said that, I don't think securing sensitive information at item level in a shared list by using workflows is a good idea. What if the workflow stops working someday for some reason? Not a rare case when you upgrade your SP deployment to the next version... People would keep using that list by relying on the assumption that their information is secured and I can imagine that that can create a lot of trouble for some. Besides if the number of items in that list is going to be "high" you will have performance issues and potentially hit the [soft limits of SharePoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.14).aspx).

I would create a separate list for each department to store their notes or create a folder in the Note List for each department, lock it down to the corresponding department and ask that department's users to put their notes into their department's folder.

Comment: Thank you Serkan, I must nothing but agree. All you say makes sense. I will do it by using several tables as you advised. Jan

Comment: Good choice jan, even though there have been many requests to implement column based security, it is not in the product. It is also easier to manage and requires no custom implementation, which will decrease maintenance and migration costs in the future.